# C++ Coin Toss Confusion

Tags: c++, enums

So for my class assignment I was told to make a coin toss program but in a different fashion than those I found online.
The goal of our lab was to create a coin toss program in which it will run 4 different times and it will "succeed" if it gets 4 heads or 4 tails. If it fails (ie. 2 tails 2 heads) then it will keep trying until it gets that 4 heads or 4 tails. 
So far I have

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

enum coinFace { head , tail };

void coinToss()
{
    for (int flips = 1; flips <= 4; flips++)
    {
        int result = rand() % 3;
        if (result == 1)
            cout << "Heads" << endl;
        else
            cout << "Tails" << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    unsigned seed;
    int trials;
    cout << "Please enter the seed." << endl;
    cin >> seed;
    cout << "How many trials would you like?" << endl;
    cin >> trials;
    srand(seed);
    coinToss();

    return 0;
}
```

I'm very lost at this point. I don't understand how to use the enum fuction and I don't really know how to... continue from here.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oxwt9.jpg This is the post to the assignment. I want to be able to learn instead of simply receiving the answer please! But I don't know how to go on from here so I'm most likely going to need lots of help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `int result = rand() % 3;` will produce three numbers: 0, 1, and 2. `if (result == 1)` heads. If result == 0 or 2, tails. This does not seem fair to me.

Comment: Suggestion: Rather than `for (int flips = 1; flips <= 4; flips++)`, simplify and go `for (int flips = 0; flips < 4; flips++)`

Answer (score 0):

Because you only need to store the state of head/tail, you can use enum or what ever. What you need to add are followings: 1) Count the times of head/tail. 2) Judge fail/success.